# Is it possible to block email sender names in sendmail on CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, email-server, sendmail

We have been getting a lot of fake emails sent to employees acting like our CEO and our firewall is not capable of blocking specifically what we want. The emails come in from regular gmail accounts and their first and last name is the same as the CEO and they emails header looks something like this.

Subject:    some minutes
Date:   Wed, 28 Aug 2019 18:04:39 +0100
From:   CEO Name 
To:     Employee@email.com

So for the not so tech savvy employees, they may think it is the CEO. I know in sendmail you can block emails by domain or username but is it possible to block by the name and we can whitelist our CEOs email.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

- use procmail as local delivery agent (as I remember, it should be the default on CentOS, or stick `FEATURE(local_procmail,`', `procmail -t -Y -a $h -d $u')dnl` in /etc/sendmail.mc)
- In /etc/procmailrc have a line like (https://regex101.com/r/uREw5R/1/):

```
    :0 
    * "?your ceo name"?\s?
    /home/fakemail/mail/
```

This will divert all email with a display name 'your ceo name' and domain part of gmail.com to a fakemail mailbox (which must exist), for examination. 'course if your CEO writes from gmail, you're out of luck.

Answer (score -1):

Sendmail offers various options to block an email address, domain name or IP address using access database.

File /etc/mail/access act as an access control for your Sendmail smtp server. With this file you can define:

- Who we accept mail from
- Who we accept relaying from
- Who we will not send to etc

Configuration

```
# vi /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

Make sure following line exists in your configuration file (otherwise you need to add/append following line):

```
FEATURE(`access_db’)dnl
```

Save the file and exit to shell prompt. Now, open /etc/mail/access file:

```
# vi /etc/mail/access
```

To block junk or spam mail use following format

```
spam@domain.com REJECT
192.168.1.100 REJECT
202.54.1.100/255.0.0.0 REJECT
```

Save the file. Once sendmail.mc or access file is modified, you need to regenerate /etc/mail/sendmail.cf or rebuild the access database. Type any one of the following commands:

```
# cd /etc/mail
# make
```

OR

```
# m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

Restart the sendmail:

```
# /etc/init.d/sendmail restart
```

Other options supported by access database

- OK – Accept email FROM: or TO: specified address
- DISCARD – Do not accept email FROM: or TO: specified address
- REJECT – Drop email with an error FROM: or TO: specified address
- HATER – Use check_mail and check_realy rules for email
- FRIEND – Do not use check_mail and check_realy rules for email
- ERROR:ecode:etext – Drop email with specified error code (ecode) and error text message (etext).